# How to get the line number of a field declaration with Javassist?

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

This is a follow up to: [How to get the line number of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834887/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-a-method)

I have a `java.lang.reflect.Field` instance and want to know at which line the declaration was made of in the declaring class.

Currently I have a `CtField` but it lacks a `getLineNumber()` method.

```
public static int getLineNumberOf(Field field) {
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctClass = cp.getCtClass(field.getDeclaringClass().getName());
    CtField ctField = ctClass.getDeclaredField(field.getName());

    ctField.getLineNumber(); 
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  that one is missing.
}
```

What is the right way to get the line number?

---

Edit: After investigating on that topic is seems that line numbers of fields are not stored in class files. But it is possible in some cases, as described here: [java.objectweb.asm Line Number of Methods and Attributes](http://osdir.com/ml/java.objectweb.asm/2008-09/msg00005.html)

> For fields that are initialized in place, the anchor is the line
>   number right before FIELDPUT instruction in  method body, withe
>   line number entry right before it that is pointing outside of the
>    method line number range (i.e. outside of the first line number
>   entry in  method and the last one before visitEnd()). There is a
>   corner case, if constructor is the last method and fields are placed
>   at the end of the method. It also won't work if fields initialization
>   been declared in the constructor body.

Comment: You could count the imports and class declaration then start counting by field indecies (by just iterating over the fields and adding one). Aside from that I don't think there's really any other way.