# BCEL bytecode, how to get method source line?

Tags: java, methods, bytecode, bcel

I want to get the number of line where a method is in a class. I was doing this getting the first LineNumber of the method, and getting the *src_line* from that. But, it doesn't work because comments and initializations doesn't have LineNumber initialization.

Actual code that doesn't work:

```
MethodGen.getLineNumbers()[0].getSourceLine() - 1
```

In  my project, I've instances of `Method` and `MethodGen`. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose with “comments and initializations” you mean “comments and declarations”. Then, you already gave the answer yourself. These artifacts have no line number stored in the class file, so it’s not possible to get their line number. It also has been summed up in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988012/2711488) already. Note that even for executable instructions, the compiler dependent precision imposes limitations as discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67409058/2711488).

Comment: Yes, I mean declarations. So, if it's impossible, I've to have to do a post-processing reading the ".class" file, searching the method with a counter. Do yo agree?

Comment: There is no kind of processing that can regain information that is not there. You can’t get the line number from the .class file. Only processing the .java file will do.

Comment: And with javassist? ([link](https://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/bytecode/MethodInfo.html)) There is a Class named MethodInfo that does that task. (Thank u so much btw)

Comment: *Which* task does it solve? I see a method `getLineNumber​(int pos)` which returns the line number associated with the bytecode instruction at the specified code location, subject to precisely those limitations we just discussed. `getLineNumber​(0)` does not differ from `MethodGen.getLineNumbers()[0].getSourceLine()`.