# Why the LocalVariableTable length of JVM ByteCode is incorrect in try-catch statement?

Tags: jvm, bytecode, local-variables

I write a simple code:

```java
L11    public void sum2() {
L12        int a = 25;
L13        try {
L14            int b = 8;
L15            if (a > 20) {
L16                int k = a + b;
L17                System.out.println("k=" + k);
L18            }
L19        } catch (Exception e) {
L20            e.printStackTrace();
L21        }
L22    }
```

I think the scope of variable b must be in the try statement, which is line 15~18.

But actually， when i use javap generate bytecode :

```
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
             3    41    44   Class java/lang/Exception
      LineNumberTable:
        line 12: 0
        line 14: 3
        line 15: 6
        line 16: 12
        line 17: 16
        line 21: 41
        line 19: 44
        line 20: 45
        line 22: 49
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           16      25     3     k   I
            6      35     2     b   I
           45       4     2     e   Ljava/lang/Exception;
            0      50     0  this   Lcom/buzz/asm/util/Sum;
            3      47     1     a   I
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 3
        frame_type = 252 /* append */
          offset_delta = 41
          locals = [ int ]
        frame_type = 66 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */
          stack = [ class java/lang/Exception ]
        frame_type = 4 /* same */
```

The scope of variable b is line 15~21? (start=6,end=41) ,Why?

Why the LocalVariableTable of JVM ByteCode is incorrect?

Comment: The `LineNumberTable` attribute maps executable code, more precisely, the beginning of executable code to a line number, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988012/2711488) But even in this regard, [results may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67414130/2711488) It is not precise enough to map the scope of local variables, given as bytecode range, back to the correct range of line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a breakdown of the LocalVariableTable for your method:

`this` is the reference to the current object, it’s always in slot 0 and is in scope for the entire method.

`a` is in slot 1 and is in scope from bytecode instruction 3 to instruction 50 (the entire method).

`b` is in slot 2 and is in scope from instruction 6 to instruction 41 (the try block and the following code).

`k` is in slot 3 and is in scope from instruction 16 to instruction 41 (inside the if statement in the try block).

`e` is in slot 2 and is in scope from instruction 45 to instruction 49 (the catch block).

The scope of a variable in Java is determined by where it is declared. In your code, the variable `b` is declared inside the `try` block, so its scope is limited to that block and any blocks nested within it.

The `Start` and `Length` values in the `LocalVariableTable` represent the range of bytecode instructions over which the variable is in scope. The `Start` value is the index of the first bytecode instruction where the variable is in scope, and the `Length` is the number of bytecode instructions for which the variable remains in scope.

In your case, `b` is in slot `2` and is in scope from bytecode instruction `6` to instruction `41`. This range includes the entire `try` block and the following code, up to the start of the `catch` block. This is because the `catch` block is a separate scope, and `b` is not in scope there.

So, the scope of `b` is not just lines 15-18 in your source code, but rather it extends from its declaration to the end of the `try` block and includes any additional code up to the start of the `catch` block. This is consistent with Java’s scoping rules, where a variable is in scope from the point it is declared until the end of the block in which it is declared.