# Is there any way that Java could get current file name and current line number?

Tags: java, file, logging

In C++, the file of the source code and current line number is decided by **FILE** and **INLINE**, which is decided at compiling time, is there any method in Java that could do the similar thing?  The file and line number is decided at compiling time instead of runtime?  this will be convenient for log.  I kind of doubt that use runtime method to detect these information will decrease the performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get source file-name/line-number from a java.lang.Class object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483421/how-to-get-source-file-name-line-number-from-a-java-lang-class-object)

Comment: Take a look at using [Apache logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html) services, which allows you to specify a file and line number (among other pieces of info) in a log format, which can be printed to the screen or written to a file.

Comment: William Price, Thanks for you information, very useful

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29) and something like

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
```

Output includes the current method and line number (if debugging was compiled in). 
For example,

```
com.stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Comment: new Throwable().getStackTrace() would be more efficient

Comment: Isn't that an expensive operation?

Comment: @dkatzel It's a way to get current file name and line number; I speak not as to its' efficiency.

Comment: System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]); I have tested this, it seems this will scan the call stack, which doesn't performance as good as I expect