# Spring Aop logging line number incorrect

Tags: spring, logging, aop

I am using spring aop to do logging for my application :
I have before after and afterthrowing advice configured but the line numbers that I see is not of the target class but that of the class used for logging 
How can I solve this
Below is my configuration

Spring xml :

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false" />
```

Class used for logging :

```
package com.digilegal.services.ahc.logging;

import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Aspect
public class AHCLogging {

    @Before("execution(* com.digilegal.services..*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();

        if (!Modifier.isPrivate(signature.getModifiers())
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("get")
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("set")
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("is")) {
            log.trace("ENTER METHOD ::"
                    + signature.getReturnType().getSimpleName() + " "
                    + signature.getName() + "("
                    + paramterType(signature.getParameterTypes()) + ")");
        }

    }

    @After("execution(* com.digilegal.services..*.*(..))")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)     joinPoint.getSignature();

        if (!Modifier.isPrivate(signature.getModifiers())
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("get")
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("set")
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("is")) {
            log.trace("EXIT METHOD ::"
                    + signature.getReturnType().getSimpleName() + " "
                    + signature.getName() + "("
                    + paramterType(signature.getParameterTypes()) + ")");
        }
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.digilegal.services..*.*        (..))",throwing= "error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)     joinPoint.getSignature();

        if (!Modifier.isPrivate(signature.getModifiers())
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("get")
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("set")
                && !signature.getName().startsWith("is")) {
            log.error("EXCEPTION IN METHOD ::"
                    + signature.getReturnType().getSimpleName() + " "
                    + signature.getName() + "("
                    + paramterType(signature.getParameterTypes()) + ")");
            log.error("Exception",error);
        }
    }

    private String paramterType(Class<?>[] classes) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String returnValue = "";

        for (Class<?> string : classes) {
            buffer.append(Modifier.toString(string.getModifiers()));
            buffer.append(" ");
            buffer.append(string.getSimpleName());
            buffer.append(",");
        }

        returnValue = buffer.toString();

        if (returnValue.trim().length() > 0) {
            returnValue = returnValue.substring(0, returnValue.length() -         1);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or is it suppose to be like this

Thanks

Nirav

Comment: There is nothing in there mentioning line numbers so I'm not sure what you are asking about. Also you are aware of the fact that spring already has a class that can log these things for you (instead of adding your own?). Check the [`CustomizableTraceInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/CustomizableTraceInterceptor.html)

Comment: Cool thanks for pointing out about the Spring class it would help a lot but the thing i am talking about is this :Apr 04, 2015 15:25:08:775 TRACE LoginBean:30 - ENTER METHOD ::void doLogin(public ActionEvent) where 30 is the line number of the logging class and not LoginBean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is not specifically a Spring AOP problem but just the way Log4j works, see Javadoc for [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html):

> **L**
>
> Used to output the line number ***from where the logging request was issued.***
>
> WARNING Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

So my recommendation is to use a pattern layout without line number and use Spring AOP's capability of determining line numbers, roughly like this:

```java
joinPoint.getSourceLocation().getLine()
```

Comment: Well, if it does, please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: This method `joinPoint.getSourceLocation().getLine()` is not supported by Spring-AOP up to 4.2.2. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: I am really not a Spring user, but have you seen [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.html)? I do not know if it helps. Be it as it might, the problem in this question was wrong Log4J usage anyway.

Comment: Shame,   does does not work on Spring 4.2.4 either... Darn it!

Comment: How about using full AspectJ in Spring via LTW, then?